# what is the difference いadjective+く and いadjective+さ?

Tags: grammar

いadjective can be an adverb

速く走る (いadjective+く + verb)

what does this mean

(noun+いadjective+く)

eg
駅の近く

海の近くに

遠くに島が見えた。

if this a noun、
what's the difference between いadjective+さ

Comment: 近く and 遠く are a special nouns and are completely different from 近さ and 遠さ.

Comment: i see, is there any more adjectives except 近く and 遠く?

Comment: Off the top of my head, 多く can also be used that way. For instance, 多くの人

Comment: how do i know if that adjective can use this?

Comment: You can check a dictionary to see if it has a noun entry for the く form.